# Unable to SSH into server when using passwordless SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh, mac-osx

This is probably an idiotic question, but I'll try and provide as much information as possible. If you need any extra details, then please let me know.

I have a Mac running Ventura and an AlmaLinux virtual machine running in VMWare Fusion Pro 13. AlmaLinux is version 9.1.

First I created my SSH keypair on macOS:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/localdevonly
```

Then I made a `config` file in `~/.ssh/config` also on macOS.

That file contains this:

```
Host localdev
    HostName 172.16.91.137
    User simon
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/localdevonly
```

Then I uploaded the SSH public key:

```
scp ~/.ssh/localdevonly.pub simon@localdev:/home/simon/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I changed the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file in AlmaLinux:

```
chmod 444 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then I added the SSH key to the SSH Agent on macOS:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/localdevonly
```

Then I try to login from macOS:

```
ssh localdev -v
```

Which gives the following output:

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/simon/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/simon/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for localdev
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.91.137 [172.16.91.137] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/simon/.ssh/localdevonly type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/simon/.ssh/localdevonly-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.16.91.137:22 as 'simon'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/simon/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:bVk7Pm91A5qGjVI+6o+nAo8+4qm+sIyrgmZiwJhH1Dw
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/simon/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '172.16.91.137' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/simon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 3 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/simon/.ssh/localdevonly ED25519 SHA256:CsSaNoNXrF/Fdxfiaj8NR1b1TC2/lRy7aXpyt7Bm9sk explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: simon@Simons-Mac-Studio.local ED25519 SHA256:ADJnS0Xnk/Al1TJrahM8AWDXKhrapjwxhz9P17z3cUw agent
debug1: Will attempt key: MuzikStrm ED25519 SHA256:hu4rJT60Pk1Jx9IT73wlmrLPIg6ya3In1JdNFkIVlso agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/simon/.ssh/localdevonly ED25519 SHA256:CsSaNoNXrF/Fdxfiaj8NR1b1TC2/lRy7aXpyt7Bm9sk explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: simon@Simons-Mac-Studio.local ED25519 SHA256:ADJnS0Xnk/Al1TJrahM8AWDXKhrapjwxhz9P17z3cUw agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: MuzikStrm ED25519 SHA256:hu4rJT60Pk1Jx9IT73wlmrLPIg6ya3In1JdNFkIVlso agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
simon@172.16.91.137: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I have no idea how I can fix this problem. I'm stumped. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Comment: In general: you can’t debug server issues from the client alone. Check the logs on the server. Increase verbosity if necessary

Comment: You need to ensure restricted permissions for both file `.ssh/authorized_keys` and dir `.ssh` on the server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it was the wrong permissions on the .ssh folder! Thank you so much!

Comment: In your `ssh` config file I would add `PreferredAuthentications publickey` and `IdentitiesOnly yes`.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, `/var/log/secure` would have flagged that the `authorized_keys` file or `~/.ssh` dir wasn't accepted due to permissions (mode) or ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Please, set the following permissions and try again:

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

And it is better to use `ssh-copy-id` instead of `scp` command.